# Display Info From Foreign Table into View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

In my view I am using:

```
@model ALSummary.Models.MRecord
```

`MRecord` has a property called `ACID` that holds the primary key of another table called `ACInfo`.

Now my model for `MRecord` is:

```
public partial class MRecord
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public System.DateTime DateEntered { get; set; }

    public int ACID { get; set; }

    public virtual ACInfo ACInfo { get; set; }
}
```

In my *Create* view for `MRecord`, instead of displaying the `ACID`, I want to display another piece of information from the `ACInfo` table.

So the original view was:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ACID, "ACID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ACID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ACID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

But I want to display another piece of info that corresponds to that `ACID` by doing this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ACID, "ACID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ACInfo.RegNum, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ACID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

In my `HttpGet Create ActionResult` I created a new instance of `MRecord` for informational purposes:

```
public ActionResult Create(int? id)
{
    MRecord newMRecord = new MRecord();
    DateTime yesterday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
    newMRecord.DateEntered = DateTime.Today.Date;

   return View(newMRecord);
}
```

How do get `ACID` which is of type `int` to equal `RegNum` which is of type `string`? or is it not possible?

Comment: Not clear what your wanting to do. Is `ACInfo.RegNum` convertible to typeof `int`? And are you wanting to display a textbox for `ACID` but display the initial value in the view so that its equal to the value of `ACInfo.RegNum`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke `RegNum` is not convertible to type `int`... and let's say that in the `ACInfo` table there is a record.. `ID` is `1` and the `RegNum` for that is `T1PS`.. and in my *Create* view for the `MRecord` instead of displaying `1` for `ACID` I want to display `T1PS` which corresponds with `1`

Comment: Still not clear, but I'm assuming you want to select record from the `ACInfo` table and assign it to a new `MRecord`, in which case shouldn't you be using a dropdownlist to display all `ACInfo` items (in which case you can display the `RegNum` property but bind `ACID` to the `ID` property)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have done that with the ddl, but I was wondering if it is possible to bind the `ACID` property to the `ID` but have it be an *EditorFor* and not a ddl?

Comment: Short answer is no, but its not really clear what you would be wanting to achieve with that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a view model. It makes handling situations like this trivial. Essentially you just create a class that has all the properties you want to edit on it:

```
public class MRecordViewModel
{
    public string ACInfoRegNum { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you simply map to/from this view model in your controller actions. For example:

```
var model = new MRecordViewModel
{
    ACInfoRegNum = mrecord.ACInfo.RegNum
};
```

However, what is less unclear (and what you need to determine) is how you want to handle the posted value. Should altering the `RegNum` update an existing `ACInfo` or create a new one? And, then, what if there's an existing `ACInfo` already with that `RegNum`? Should you attach that existing `ACInfo` instance or still create a new one? If you want to update, then you'll need to pass around the `ACID` as well, so you can fetch the existing `ACInfo` instance and update it. You can use a hidden field if you like, or you can just query the `MRecord` fresh on post and get the `ACInfo` instance from there (which is probably better). If you want to create a new one, and you don't want duplicate `RegNum`s, then you'll need to query using the value posted for `ACInfoRegNum` and then attach that instance to your `MRecord` instance instead.